# Is it possible to export GIFI from QuickBooks Online?

Tags: export, import, quickbooks-online

I use QuickBooks Online for my business transactions. Now I need to do corporation tax return and I want to use [UFileT2](https://www.ufile.ca/products/ufilet2) for this.

So I need to import data to Ufile. For import I need to have [GIFI](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/corporations/corporation-income-tax-return/completing-your-corporation-income-tax-t2-return/general-index-financial-information-gifi.html) file.

I found this regarding [GIFI in QuickBooks Online Accountant](https://quickbooks.intuit.com/ca/resources/pro-accountants/qboa-use-workpapers-gifi-file/).

But can't find GIFI in QuickBooks Online.

Is it possible to export GIFI from QuickBooks Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at this time, you'd need QuickBooks Online Accountant.

[How does one export GIFI (General Index of Financial Information) from QBO?][1]https://quickbooks.intuit.com/learn-support/en-ca/reports-and-accounting/how-does-one-export-gifi-general-index-of-financial-information/00/292883